# How to auto answer 'yes' in running a bash script?

Tags: bash, docker, io-redirection

I am running a bash script inside a dockerfile such as

```
bash Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I am wondering how to automatically answer 'yes' prompted in the command? I have tried

```
echo yes | bash Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

But still get a long list of

[image]

Comment: `yes(1)`? Or `expect` for more complicated interaction.

Comment: have you read this https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/#linux-macos ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two big problems. First, you posted a picture, instead of a text version of the messages. With your rep, you should know better.

The second is that your `Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh` expects probaby more than one `yes` or a `no`. And `echo yes` just gives:

```
$ echo yes
yes
```

So, you should use `yes yes` (or `yes no` depending on what you want).

```
$ yes yes | head -3
yes
yes
yes
```

Comment: hm. yes (no pun intended); don't know why I missed that